# SQL - `group by` not giving expected results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have difficult with what seem to be simple problem. With data as in the following table

table1

```
num_users | time_taken
----------------------
10.1      | 11.2
10.1      | 11.5
10.2      | 11.1
10.4      | 11.9
11.01     | 12.2
11.1      | 11.8
11.7      | 13.2
11.72     | 13.1
```

I want to compute the avg. `time_taken` for each `num_users` value rounded to 0 decimal. Here is what I've tried.

```
select 
 round(num_users,0) as num_users
 , round(avg(time_taken),1) as time_taken
from table1 as a
group by a.num_users
order by a.num_users
```

However this gives multiple rows for each distinct `num_users` value (rounded to 0 decimal) - any ideas here ?

expected output

```
  num_users | time_taken
    ----------------------
    10      | 11.4
    11      | 12.0
    12      | 13.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Repeat the expression in the `group by`:

```
select round(num_users, 0) as num_users,
       round(avg(time_taken), 1) as time_taken
from table1 as a
group by round(num_users, 0)
order by round(num_users, 0);
```

I say to repeat it, because the name of the expression is the same as the name of the column.  Alternatively, you could write:

```
select round(num_users, 0) as new_num_users,
       round(avg(time_taken), 1) as time_taken
from table1 as a
group by new_num_users
order by new_num_users;
```

Or even:

```
group by 1
order by 1
```

Even if you drop the qualifier from the `group by a.num_users`, Postgres will still interpret it as the column name rather than the new alias name.